# Surrogate character to visualize a space like ̺ this, but without combining?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, special-characters, typography

I'm looking for a character in Unicode like this (in black):

[image: combining inverted bridge below]

The problem with *COM­BI­NING INVERTED BRID­GE BELOW* (code point `U+033A`, `\xCC\xBA` in UTF-8) is that it must be combined with another character. I need the character stand-alone.

Combined with a space:   ̺  (easily lost if you try to delete the character to its left-hand side)

First letter of word, non-spacing bridge, rest:   ̺Not ̺what ̺I ̺want (`N&#x33a;ot` ...)

Is there such a character, a **non-combining**, **spacing** *inverted bridge below*?

Comment: See [How can I best display a blank space character?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/91255/35482)

Comment: Greate! *blank* and *underbracket* are the relevant keywords here. Do you want to post an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote an answer by [Ben](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/77302/ben)
to [How can I best display a blank space character?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/91255/35482#91256),
these two underbracket characters are possibilities:

- “Open Box” (code point U+2423, looks like ‘␣’).
  This can be entered in HTML as `&blank;`, `&#x2423;` and `&#9251;`.
- “Bottom Square Bracket” (code point U+23B5, looks like ‘⎵’).
  This can be entered in HTML as `&#x23B5;` and `&#9141;`.

You can see these characters in PDF files
on Unicode.org [here](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2400.pdf) and [here](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2300.pdf).